# How to share the exact same canvas in a video call?

Tags: video, three.js, twilio, webrtc

I am building a video app where I want all participants to see the exact same canvas during the call so that when someone is rotating the 3D object everyone can see that in real-time. Now every participant gets their own instance of the canvas, which is not what I want. I am working with Twilio's programmable video app (React) and Three.js. I found [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/capture-stream) on Google developers site, but can't figure out how to potentially use it to my advantage. Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to approach this. You could replicate the scene on everyone's client and share input or camera motion through something like SignalR, or some other interconnection library. Or you could find a way to broadcast the host's rendering to a streamed video, and send client mouse input back to the host for camera processing. Regardless, you'll probably see latency as your biggest hurdle.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I am going to build a prototype to test how well it will perform with multiple participants to find out if this is a way to move forwards. I've found this Draw app https://github.com/twilio/draw-with-twilio and this add on to the Quick Twilio Video React app https://www.twilio.com/blog/open-source-video-app-reactjs-datatrack-snack-chat. I basically want to do something similar as the Draw thing but in the React app.

Comment: There are probably dozens of ways to achieve this. One of them is with web-sockets (https://socket.io) but you’ll need to set up a server that runs Node.js so you can broadcast info across all users.

Answer (score 0):

When you move an object, an event is fired... If you capture it and stream the data to other clients (with Sockets or WebRTC), you'll be able to do apply that movement to the client. It is quite similar to real time videogames with ThreeJS

Comment: Thank you! Guess it could be very similar to games. Didn't know you could build them with Three.js. I've found this Draw app github.com/twilio/draw-with-twilio and this add-on to the Quick Twilio Video React app twilio.com/blog/…. I basically want to do something similar as the Draw thing but in the React app. Trying to understand how to work with the room-object and the DataTrack component. Not working for me at the moment.